# OrientDB slow Edge ETL creation

Tags: performance, etl, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm new to OrientDB, having had a little experience with Neo4J, and I'm having performance issues when trying to load and create Edges using the OETL.BAT tool. I need to create ~4.4million edges between nodes (roughly 42million, not all are used in this stage of etl). The "Customer" nodes are already loaded, and the edge list I'm loading is very simple (as below) and simply has a source & destination ID for each edge, its intention is to model payments between customers.

At the moment I'm getting a throughput of ~23-30 per second, according to the etl tool. I've resorted to using a CSV file, rather than a JDBC connection to my RDBMS, and I'm in "plocal" mode as well.

Is there any faster way of doing this?  or am I perhaps taking the wrong approach?

**Customer - Vertex**
CISNumber, Name

**PAID - Edge**
SourceCISNumber,DestCISNumber, Amount, TransactionCount

```
{
 "source": { "file": { "path": "/datafiles/PersonalCustomers/Edges.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "row": {} },
 "transformers": [
    {"csv": {} }, 
    {"merge": {"joinFieldName": "SourceCISNumber", "lookup": "Customer.CISNumber"} },
    {"vertex": {"class": "Customer", "skipDuplicates": true} },
    { "edge": 
        { 
            "class": "PAID",
            "joinFieldName": "DestCISNumber",
            "lookup": "Customer.CISNumber",
            "unresolvedLinkAction": "SKIP",
            "edgeFields":
                {
                    "Volume": "${input.Transactioncount}", 
                    "Value": "${input.Amount}"
                }
        }
    },
    {"field": {"fieldNames": ["SourceCISNumber", "DestCISNumber", "Transactioncount", "Amount"], "operation": "remove" } }
  ],
   "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:/orientdb/databases/Customers",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "batchCommit": 500,
       "useLightweightEdges" : true,
       "classes": [
         {"name": "PAID", "extends": "E"},
       ]
    },
    "indexes": [
         {"class":"Customer", "fields":["CISNumber:long"] }
       ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053190/orientdb-fastest-batchimport/37065876#37065876)

Answer (score 0):

You should put "batchCommit": 1000 in the "loader". 
Also "parallel": true in the "config"